# Update column using a select query order by highest value descing

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m returning a set of records from the table ordering by the highest mark.

```
Select name,score from score_tbl order by score desc
```

Now what I want to do is on that `score_tbl` there is a column named `position` which I want to use an update statement to update that column based on the select query so the position is updated based user’s score

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to update the "position" value for all rows in your table based on the "score" field.  In other words, the row with the highest score gets a position value of 1.  Try this:

```
UPDATE score_tbl
FROM (
  SELECT name, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) ScorePosition
  FROM score_tbl
) src
SET position = src.ScoreRank
WHERE name = src.name
```

This uses the "src" derived table where you generate the rankings to update your target table.  This assumes "name" is the PK for your table.

Not sure what your DB is, so you will probably need to adjust the query a bit.  But this should get you going.  Let me know how it goes.

**Updated**
Try the query below:

```
UPDATE competitors 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        RANK() OVER w AS 'ScorePosition' 
    FROM competitors 
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY score DESC)
) src ON competitors.id = src.id
SET position = src.ScorePosition;
```

It looks like windows functions were introduced in MySQL 8.0, so you'd need access to that version.  I don't have access to this version, so I wasn't able to test.  But let me know if it works.

Also, take a look at this post for some help:

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: i'm get an error. let me paste in here my real query as i modified along side your code : UPDATE competitors
FROM (
  SELECT username, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) ScorePosition
  FROM competitors
) src
SET position = src.ScoreRank
WHERE id = src.id

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (
  SELECT username, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) ScorePosition
  FRO' at line 2

Comment: It looks like windows functions are not supported until MySQL 8.0.2.  So, depending on what version you have, you may not be able to do it this way.  See updated answer.